# Downloading PDF with Meteor with Java proxy

Tags: java, spring, meteor

I need to serve a PDF I create via Meteor to a client in AngularJS. I am proxying Meteor with a Java REST server. When I execute the REST server and the client locally, it works correctly: I download the PDF with the correct name and the correct content. In order to generate the PDF, I am invoking the remote Meteor (the one in my production environment).

However, when I deploy my Spring Boot application, I am getting a weird behaviour: I download a PDF with the correct name, but the PDF content is actually HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" class="__meteor-css__" href="/004b317ac1d5291ab47b558b4735378956c08e9b.css?meteor_css_resource=true">    
<script type="text/javascript">__meteor_runtime_config__ = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent("%7B%22meteorRelease%22%3A%22METEOR%401.2.1%22%2C%22PUBLIC_SETTINGS%22%3A%7B%22settings_loaded%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22ROOT_URL%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2F100.100.100.87%3A3000%2F%22%2C%22ROOT_URL_PATH_PREFIX%22%3A%22%22%2C%22autoupdateVersion%22%3A%2243f34f41b93ffc5a984b14127100e2a44d37dda1%22%2C%22autoupdateVersionRefreshable%22%3A%226ca0239ca5c7c0b94fa69f3f0d3cd4bb0ad9b8e6%22%2C%22autoupdateVersionCordova%22%3A%22none%22%7D"));</script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/8e08c879e7f7d3d9de60bbfd488162da99419f40.js?meteor_js_resource=true"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my Java code to download stream the PDF to the client:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "get/pdf/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/pdf")
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getPdfContrattoById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {

    String urlStr = buildPdfUrlFromIdContratto(id); // build the URL correctly

    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(urlStr);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    InputStream pdfFile = null;
    try {
        pdfFile = url.openStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new BatException(e.getMessage());
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    int nRead;
    byte[] data = new byte[2048];

    try {
        while ((nRead = pdfFile.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
            buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
        }
        buffer.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new BatException("Errore nella generazione del PDF: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    byte[] bytes = buffer.toByteArray();

    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
 responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf("application/pdf"));
    responseHeaders.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", "File " + id.toString() + ".pdf");

    ResponseEntity<byte[]> re = ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .headers(responseHeaders)
            .contentType(
                    MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"))
            .body(bytes);
    return re;
}
```

Where can I look for the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I did this recently. It worked for me. 
Replace

```
responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf("application/pdf"));
responseHeaders.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", "File " + id.toString() + ".pdf");
```

With

```
response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE);
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(response.getOutputStream());
osw.write(yourPDFFileContents);
osw.flush();
osw.close();
response.flushBuffer();
```

Note response is of type HttpServletResponse.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to replace the media type; the other header (ContentDisposition) should be the same. Without replacing my ResponseEntity with your HttpServletResponse, nothing changes.

Comment: Your request should contain a response. EG:  public void getPdfContrattoById(@PathVariable("id") Long id, HttpServletResponse response) then you use that response to sent it back.